# 301 redirect in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, vs-web-site-project

So we have a client whereby we are hosting their site but with 2 different domains mapped (we have bindings for both domains) to the same site in IIS. this is primarily because when they started with us they could only purchase the domain they didn't ultimately want to use going forwards.

For example the domains are www.some-thing.com and www.something.com.

They have asked if I can put a 301 permanent redirect in on the URL with the hyphen so then users should always go to the non hyphen version of the site.

I have tried URL rewrite rules and using the HTTP redirect in IIS however the site is then in a re-direct loop and I think this is down to the fact I have both domains bound to the site in IIS.

Help !!

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mathew in generalyou are asking to navigate from one domain to another right?

Comment: Effectively yes but the 3rd party who are working with us on some SEO are moaning that there are 2 URLS running for the same site so this is the part I need to combat ;-)

Comment: @mathew here is the [link](https://forums.iis.net/t/1182741.aspx) it shows about how to apply rules to navigate from one domain to another

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. I have URL re-write installed in IIS and have tried adding a rule but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You sayinf u tried this one and not working? if so can you post your config

Comment: Thank you, I read the article you linked me to and fixed the rules.

Comment: Added the actual answer as answer try to accept even if that link dont work other users coming from google  will able to find the answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this URL Rewrite .Here is the [Source](https://forums.iis.net/t/1182741.aspx)

```
<rule name="fromadd Host Name" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"  pattern="^anitkb\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="To address" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```